# Empty names returned in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is my dynamic query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NAME asc) peta_rn, peta_query.* 
    From (Select BOOK, PageINT, PageCHAR NAME, TYPE, PDF From test1 cdn
                            Inner Join test2 cwi
                                On cwi.ID = cdn.ID Where 1=1  And IsNull(NAME,'''') Like COALESCE(@0,'''') + ''%''  )
                                 as peta_query) peta_paged WHERE peta_rn>@1 AND peta_rn<=@2',N'@0 varchar(4000),@1 bigint,@2 bigint',@0='Miller',@1=0,@2=50
```

As you can see I am only searching for `Miller` but I get names which are empty too. What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: U should try replace the INNER JOIN by a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: This isn't the answer. The question is why would records with empty names be returned?

Comment: You should try to understand the question. I want it to be INNER JOIN only but return Names where it contains Miller. Are you able to understand the question?

Comment: And I think _test2cwi_ is two words -> table _test2_ and alias _cwi_

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Changed that. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem in your SQL expression that may be the source of the issue within the inner select:

```
From (Select BOOK, PageINT, PageCHAR NAME, TYPE, PDF From test1 cdn
    Inner Join test2 cwi
    On cwi.ID = cdn.ID 
    Where 1=1  And IsNull(NAME,'''') Like COALESCE(@0,'''') + ''%''  )
```

I believe in the predicate `IsNull(NAME,'''') Like COALESCE(@0,'''') + ''%''` you're intending to reference  `PageCHAR NAME`, but that is not happening.

The `SELECT` statement is one of the last parts to be executed, `WHERE` will execute first and have no idea about `PageCHAR` being aliased as `NAME`.

So if your intention is to use `PageCHAR`, change your predicate to `IsNull(PageCHAR,'''') Like COALESCE(@0,'''') + ''%''`.

Where the column `NAME` is coming from I have no idea.  There may be a `NAME` column in your table somewhere, or maybe something super crazy is happening because `NAME` does exist outside the CTE, but I don't think that's it.

Also applying a function to the left side of a predicate will definitely make it not use an index, so be sure you really want to do that.

Here is a helpful link regarding the order of execution in a select statment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4536/order-of-execution-of-select-statement.aspx